# "Best" pythonic way to retrieve an item from a list based on two criteria

Tags: python, list

I have a list with r rows and three columns. The first column is an x-coordinate, the second is an y-coordinate and the third is its value.

```
Looks like e.g.
x  y  value
------------
0, 0, value
0, 1, value
0, 2, value
...
1, 0, value
1, 1, value
...
100, 0, value
100, 1, value
...
```

Based on the x and y coordinate I would like retrieve the value, preferably in a time-efficient way?

I realise this is probably not the best organisation of the list (but this is how my data is organised...).

Comment: Why not structure this into an actual multi-dimensional array...? Then `l[x][y]` is as efficient as it gets.

Comment: Have you tried something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

depends on that if you want to use other queries you can choose different data structure!
If you want to have more flexible queries you can use multi-dimensional list like this:

```
my_list = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
```

so `my_list[0][2]` would be 3 and `my_list[1][1]` would be 5

but if you're sure that you always use **x, y** to get the value I think dictionary is a better choice

so your data would be structured like this:

```
my_dict = {
   (1, 1): 'value #1',
   (1, 3): 'value #2',
   (3, 4): 'value #3',
   ...
}
```

and you'll retrieve data like this:

```
my_dict[(1, 1)] or my_dict[(3, 4)]
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there an easy way to reform the given list into a dictionary, with a list as a key?

Comment: Also note that when the dict keys are tuples, you can simplify the syntax and just omit the parentheses: `my_dict[3, 4]`.

Comment: is your list some strings in a text file? or you have a pythonic list?

Comment: @mehdy: they come from a text file, indeed and I read them with numpy.loadtxt(file, dtype='float') into a list.

Comment: so you can iterate over all lines and for each line `x, y, value = line.split(',')` will parse the line and `my_dict[int(x),(y)] = value.strip()` will populate your dictionary with proper values

Answer (score 1):

If there are never going to be duplicate coordinates, I would use a list of lists. Whether you organise it by X or Y axes is up to you.

For example:

```
lookup_table[4][5] = "the value of x4, y5"
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple two dimensional List will work for you.

> x  y  value
>
> 0, 0, value
>
> 0, 1, value
>
> 0, 2, value

`assuming max x, max y  = size_of_x_coordinate, size_of_y_coordinate  =  10, 10`

```
coordinates = [ [0]* size_of_y_coordinate ] * size_of_x_coordinate
# get value at x = 9, y = 8 just do 
coordinates[x][y]
```

Comment: Thank you! In reality, the x and y coordinates are floats, so this might be harder due to "rounding errors"?

Comment: if the coordinates are floats, it may be best to use a dictionary. The index of a list is always an integer, so in the 'list of lists' idea you're making that concept do double duty as both the index inside the list, and using it to mean the coordinate.  A dictionary would let you choose any value as the lookup.

Comment: Thank you all! I'll go with the dictionary solution! Great to learn from all of you!

Answer (score 1):

Let's say that your list is organized  like this

```
l = [(0, 0, 1), (0, 2, 5), (1, 3, 2), (0, 0, 3)]
```

then we can define a function to search in your data

```
def in_l(l,x,y):
    return [el[2] for el in l if(el[0]==x and el[1]==y)]
```

and use it

```
print in_l(l, 0, 0) # -> [1, 3]
print in_l(l, 5, 1) # -> []
print in_l(l, 1, 3) # -> [2]
```

If you are sure that there are no duplicate data points in your data,
you can define your function as

```
def in_l(l, x, y):
    for _ in l:
        if _[0]==x and _[1]==y : return _[2]
```

that returns on the 1st match and that returns `None` if it doesn't find a match

```
print in_l(l, 0, 0) # -> 1
print in_l(l, 5, 1) # -> None
print in_l(l, 1, 3) # -> 2
```

p.s. as everyone else told you, your data *structure(?)* is not appropriate

---

A possible data structure that you can use, from a comment of yours to another answer, is a dictionary

```
grid = {}
for line in open('data.csv'):
    x, y, val = map(int, line.split(',')):
    grid[x,y] = val
```

and in the following you can use your data as follows

```
x1, y1 = a_model_of_everything(42)
val1 = grid[x1,y1]
```

(no nested dictionary, no third level, just a matrix like access)

Comment: thank you! So it is best to restructure the data. I've noticed that loading it into a dictionary is rather slow (to view the content of it in Spyder), maybe because the questions asked is actually the third level in a nested dictionary. So it might be better to re-arrange my data in a nested list where, instead of repeating the x-coordinate multiple times with a matching different y coordinate, to have a nested list.

Comment: @RisingSun I have added a note to my answer about a possible data structure.